# When tab panel is added page not getting rendered, If no tab panel code the page is getting rendered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
        >
            {value === index && (
                <Box p={3}>
                    <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

when i added the above piece of code to create tabpanel, my page stops rendering, Can some one help what mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me after providing the required props as the following

```
  <TabPanel value={1} index={1}>
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
  </TabPanel>
```

I think the problem could be with the props which you are passing to the div ( ...other)